# Pull data from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, database, vba, pull

I'm trying to write a Macro/VBA that will pull certain data from different sheets, ( Basically 12 Sheets a separate sheet for each Month ) into a different sheet. I'm not sure where to start.

The Macro will need to be able to look through the rows in the 12 sheets and pull the necessary cells that meet the following criteria: I have a particular column named as category, if there is a cell with the value `debtors` in that column I would like to pull that data to the final sheet named `debtors`. I am attaching a sample Excel for your reference.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rJxNdHxXtKGHjMKIozrbV3UN4hpDpIec/view?usp=sharing

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes there is. Look into `Loops` and `For Each worksheet` methods. Return and edit your question when you have some sample code. Have a nice day.

Comment: Try to split your whole project into small chunks that you can solve. Eg one chunk will be how to loop through 12 worksheets. Antother is how to loop through all used rows in a worksheet to check your category column for `debtors` and so on. Research for every chunk how to do that. Then try to get the chunks solved one by another. If you get stuck start up a new question asking only about that chunk you are working on (and include the code you have tried). • If you think too big in the beginning you end up in a mess.

Comment: You put the tag `database` for this question. Note that Excel is **not** a database it is just a spreadsheet to calculate things. Therefore it has not the cool tools a real database has. You might consider switching to a real database like SQL Server where you could run a SQL query to join your data. Especially when you have a lot of data.